# How to add 3 strings to a list view?

Tags: android

I have this code,

```
 private void jsonParse(){
    String url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/";

    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
                try {
                    JSONObject coin = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name= coin.getString("name");
                    String price = coin.getString("price");
                    String change24 = coin.getString("percent_change_24h");

                    // Put the info to the ListView
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

which gets info from an API and I use those 3 strings for my data. How do I make those 3 strings to be printed out to my list view, on the same "bar" and other coin data to the next ones?

Comment: You should use a custom adapter for displaying custom items in list view

Answer (score 0):

You have to create xml layout that holds 3 strings listview and another layout with listview, one Model class to store data in List and ArrayAdapter class.

refer : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter the quantity of data returned from your request you should make a generic process. This is what you should do:

1. Implement the item interface using xml file as you designed it.
2. Create a model class(don't miss to generate getters and setters.) that will contains all the elements you need for your item, in your case the three strings.
3. Create an arraylist() witch contains your instances of model class
4. Pass it to a custom array adapter class where you bind the views in your item with the appropriate attributes from your model.
5. Set the list adapter with the new one.